# Is there a change of basis that transforms any finite subgroup of $GL_n(C)$ into a subgroup of $GL_n(\bar{Q})$?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I vaguely know that there is a related statement that is true... something like, if G is finite, then every representation of it can defined over some finite algebraic extension F of Q. (By defined over F, I mean that the representation is a map from G to $GL_n(F)$.) I'm not sure if this is the same as the question in my title.

Can someone recommend a reference, or at least set the facts straight?

Comment: Yes, the two questions are equivalent, and of course there is no reason to restrict to $3$-dimensional representations: if $\rho : G \to GL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is a representation, then the matrices $\rho(g), g \in G$ only have finitely many coefficients in total, so their coefficients generate a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, and the representation has image contained in $GL_n(K)$.

Comment: The coefficients of the matrices might possibly be non-algebraic so thee extension $K$ Qiaochu mentions in the comment above when starting from a complex representation, while of course finitely generated, will not be in general finite. For example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-\pi&1-\pi^2\\1&\pi\end{pmatrix}$ has order $2$.

Comment: This is why something like the argument in his answer is needed!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Absolutely. How did you come up with that example? (Is it obvious for some reason?)

Comment: I picked the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and conjugated it with $\begin{pmatrix}1&\pi\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh, that is the "obvious" thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: Mariano's comment can be turned into a different answer with some work: starting from a representation over $\mathbb{C}$ you get a representation over a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. This has some maximal ideal, which you can quotient by to get a representation over a finitely generated field of characteristic $0$, which (essentially by the Nullstellensatz) must be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then there's something to do to show that tensoring this up gives you what you started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat indirect proof. It suffices to answer this question for irreducible representations. Consider the group algebra $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[G]$, which is semisimple by Maschke's theorem. Hence by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, it's a finite product of matrix algebras over finite-dimensional division algebras over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. But since this field is algebraically closed, the only such division algebra is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, so we conclude that

$$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[G] \cong \prod_i M_{d_i}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$$

for some $d_i$. Tensoring further with $\mathbb{C}$ shows that the $d_i$ must be the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $G$, each of which occurs $d_i$ times in the decomposition of the above as a representation of $G$ in the factor $M_{d_i}$. Hence all of the irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ are defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and then the argument in the comments shows furthermore that they're defined over a finite extension $K$.

**Edit:** Mariano's comment can be turned into a different answer with some work. Starting from a representation over $\mathbb{C}$ you get a representation over a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. This has some maximal ideal, which you can quotient by to get a representation over a finitely generated field of characteristic $0$, which (by the Nullstellensatz) must be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then there's something to do to show that tensoring this up gives you what you started with.

Comment: About the edit: I think it is easiest to see that the characters of the representation don't change after this process, since they are already algebraic numbers. We can start by observing that we get a representation over a finitely generated $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-algebra (instead of just over the rationals), with traces valued in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, since then we don't have to worry about the values of the algebraic numbers after modding out by this maximal ideal.